# Lost one row in SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have two tables like this:

```
Occupied                          Subject
+----------+-----------+          +----+---------+
| idClass  | idSubject |          | id |  Name   |
+----------+-----------+          +----+---------+
|        1 |         1 |          |  1 | German  |
|        1 |         2 |          |  2 | English |
|        2 |         3 |          |  3 | Math    |
+----------+-----------+          +----+---------+
```

Now I want to get the *id* and the *Name* from all subjects which a special class occupied. I tried with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT S._id ,
       S.Name
FROM Subject S
WHERE S._id = ( SELECT O.idSubject
                FROM Occupied O
                WHERE O.idClass = '1' -- '1' is variable and represents the special class
              )
```

But I only get this result from the database:

```
+----+---------+
| id |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  2 | English |
+----+---------+
```

So I lost the *German* row. Where is my mistake?

Comment: It appears you are comparing an integer to a string literal. Are you using mysql, by any chance?

Comment: Thanks ;) The tables are generated by http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html @wildplasser I use SQLite on Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use an [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) query

```
SELECT S._id ,
       S.Name 
FROM Subject S 
INNER JOIN Occupied O ON O.idSubject = S.id
WHERE O.idClass='1';
```

As Charles stated this could be faster than having a subquery depending on database vendor and sql distribution

Comment: I did, because of FASTER statement.  Depending on database vendor, data distribution statistics, indices and query optimization results, any two query statements that generate equivalent results can generate similar performance.  Look at the query plans if available to see if there is any difference.

Comment: @Charles I see what you mean

Comment: +1. The join is preferable because it more clearly reflects the problem statement. Since the OPs example uses an uncorrelated subquery, it shouldn't make any difference. Any decent query optimizer would select an execution plan that executed the subquery once. Only a naive SQL implementation would execute the subquery once for every row. Changes to IN, I doubt you'd see any difference in execution plan (assuming some reasonable set of indices: the query optimizer would see and use the indices available.

Answer (score 1):

change equals to **IN**

```
SELECT S._id ,
       S.Name
FROM Subject S
WHERE S._id IN ( SELECT O.idSubject
                 FROM Occupied O
                 WHERE O.idClass = '1'
               )
```

Comment: Great thanks. Works like a charm now. Can you explain to me what is the exactly difference betwet equals  and IN? Does equals only math one entry and IN many or what is the difference?

Comment: IN() removes duplicates (and NULLs)

Comment: equals can match only one value but you can use IN or NOT IN set of values for example IN('1','2','3') Also, you should use joins subqueries slower than joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S._id, S.Name
FROM Subject S
WHERE EXISTS (
   (SELECT 1
    FROM  FROM Occupied O
    WHERE O.idSubject = S._id
    AND O.idClass= 1 -- probably an integer
    ) ;
```

The problem is that `WHERE S._id= (...)` expects a scalar subquery, which should yield exactly one result value. You don't want that; you want all the rows that satisfy the subquery, so you should use EXISTS() or IN() (*which is inferior wrt NULL handling* ) The implicit casting by mysql (which I presume is the OP's DBMS platform) makes the disaster complete. (in the original query, a string literal is compared to an integer column)